# Almost sure convergence of the RVs in the unit interval with CDF $x^n$.

Tags: probability-theory

Let the sequence of random variables $X_n \in [0,1]$ have CDF $\Pr[X_n < x] = x^n$. I would like to show $X_n \to 1$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$.

To prove $X_n \to 1$ in probability is easy but I cannot figure out how to show the almost sure convergence.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply apply the following criterion:
$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_n-1|>\varepsilon)<\infty \Rightarrow X_n \rightarrow 1 \; \text{a.s.}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give me a reference to read and understand how this criterion will imply $X_n \to 1$ almost surely?

Comment: @MikeL I guess this is from Borel-Cantelli's lemma.